# Настроить 301 редирект в .htaccess для магазина

Tags: .htaccess, url, редирект

Старый урл товара `web-site/product/tovar1/`, новый урл `web-site/tovar1/`
Старый урл категории `web-site/category/life-power/`, новый `web-site/ life-power/`.

Как прописать редирект, чтобы сохранить старые ссылки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот верная маска:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule product((/[^/]+)*)(\/?)$ $1$3 [L,R=301]
```

Она учитывает и когда на конце слеш есть, и когда его нет. Перенаправляет соответственно.
Подразделы тоже понимает и переносит.

Проверить можно здесь:  [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Редирект с `/product/` будет идти на главную. Если это не нужно, то исключаем этот url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/?$
RewriteRule product((/[^/]+)*)(\/?)$ $1$3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ:

```
Redirect 301 /product/tovar1/ http://web-site/tovar1/
```

Чтобы настроить редирект по маске:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://web-site/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Попробуйте `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/tovar([0-9]+)`.

Comment: пример алиаса товара begovaja-dorozhka-marathon-g652, а не tovar1

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks` в `.htaccess` присутствует?

Comment: Исправил код примера, чтобы он брал название товара целиком. Оно ведь у Вас копируется без изменений.